# Export SpectraObjects to csv in ChemoSpec

Tags: r, export

I am using ChemoSpec to analyse FTIR spectra in R.

I was able to import several csv files using files2SpectraObject, applied some of the data pre-processing procedures, such as normalization and binning, and generated new SpectraObjects with the results.

Is it possible to export data back to csv format from the generated SpectraObjects?

So far I tried this

```
write.table(ftirbin, "E:/ftirbin.txt", sep="\t")
```

and got this:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ""Spectra"" to a data.frame
```

Thanks in advance!

G

Comment: Bryan Hanson just gave the best solution to this problem (in my opinion). Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `?Spectra` you'll see how a `Spectra` object is stored.  The intensity values are in `your_object$data`, and the frequency values are in `your_object$freq`.  So you can't export the whole object (it's not a data frame, but rather a list), but you can export the pieces.  To export the frequencies in the first column, and the samples in the following columns, you can do this (example uses a built in data set, `SrE.IR`):

```
tmp <- cbind(SrE.IR$freq, t(SrE.IR$data))
colnames(tmp) <- c("freq", SrE.IR$names)
tmp <- as.data.frame(tmp) # it was a matrix
```

Then you can write it out using `write.csv` or `write.table` (check the arguments to avoid row numbers).

Comment: Thank you very much Bryan! Problem solved! This is a great R package by the way!